# How to delete a line up to the last instance of a specific character using bash?

Tags: string, bash, unix, split

I have a files with thousands of lines produced by md5, with the hash and then the path on each line. I'm searching through hundreds of sed examples but can't quite decipher them.

How would I everything up to and including the last slash on each line, then output just the file name?

```
fd373e07fd6f85085455a7d03a6ea8d8 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35545.CR2
b4108ee8509dbfd0e8fd93effbb2c87f /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35546.CR2
98188a4e073a65d39840b34446228533 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35547.CR2
7fe69f18e1a216a7a68812b1b3322764 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35548.CR2
7b48289014eddab153a819a460a46f83 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35549.CR2
832f43451691fa4e8577f66820f8714c /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35550.CR2
```

And for output, I want just the file names:

```
5DM35545.CR2
5DM35546.CR2
5DM35547.CR2
5DM35548.CR2
5DM35549.CR2
5DM35550.CR2
```

I understand I can delete just the hashes and then use basename, but I was hoping to do it in one operation, and learn a little sed.

Thanks for not trashing a newbie.

Comment: you may try `awk`, it's probably simpler to use than `sed` and there is plenty of documentation online. Basically you tell `awk` that your field separator is `-`, then output the last field.

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -F- '{ print $NF }' input.txt
```

`-F` tells `awk` the field separator, which in your case should be `-`. `$NF` means the last field. `input.txt` should be the file with the filenames, each on a different line.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```
sed 's|.*-MDT-||' data_file
```

This regexp remove everything before -MDT in every line

Comment: As your regexp includes `.*` you can only expect at most one match, so the `g` flag is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you'll do with these names, but if they are to be used later in a script that runs a loop on your file, you might as well include this transformation inside the loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r md5 file; do
    [[ -z $md5 ]] && continue
    base=${file##*-}
    echo "md5: $md5"
    echo "file:$file"
    echo "base: $base"
done < input.txt
```

---

**Test.**

```
$ while read -r md5 file; do
    [[ -z $md5 ]] && continue
    base=${file##*-}
    echo "md5: $md5"
    echo "file:$file"
    echo "base: $base"
done <<EOF
fd373e07fd6f85085455a7d03a6ea8d8 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35545.CR2
b4108ee8509dbfd0e8fd93effbb2c87f /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35546.CR2
98188a4e073a65d39840b34446228533 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35547.CR2
7fe69f18e1a216a7a68812b1b3322764 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35548.CR2
7b48289014eddab153a819a460a46f83 /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35549.CR2
832f43451691fa4e8577f66820f8714c /Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35550.CR2
EOF
md5: fd373e07fd6f85085455a7d03a6ea8d8
file:/Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35545.CR2
base: 5DM35545.CR2
md5: b4108ee8509dbfd0e8fd93effbb2c87f
file:/Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35546.CR2
base: 5DM35546.CR2
md5: 98188a4e073a65d39840b34446228533
file:/Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35547.CR2
base: 5DM35547.CR2
md5: 7fe69f18e1a216a7a68812b1b3322764
file:/Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35548.CR2
base: 5DM35548.CR2
md5: 7b48289014eddab153a819a460a46f83
file:/Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35549.CR2
base: 5DM35549.CR2
md5: 832f43451691fa4e8577f66820f8714c
file:/Volumes/yadda/20121007-083424-MDT-5DM35550.CR2
base: 5DM35550.CR2
```